# Find 2D-3D correspondence of 4 non-coplanar points

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a 3-dimensional object with 4 non-coplanar feature points. Their spatial arrangement is known, i.e., there is an "object" coordinate system and I know the 3D coordinates of these 4 feature points with respect to this coordinate system.

In a 2D projection image (e.g., a photograph from an arbitrary perspective) of this very object, I can locate the 2D coordinates of these 4 feature points but without knowing which coordinates belong to which feature point.

In other words: I have 4 distinct 2D coordinates **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d** of which I know that they each belong to exactly one of the 4 feature points **A**, **B**, **C**, and **D**. Each of the feature points has an ID, which is simply a number from 1 to 4. How can I find the correspondence between 2D projection coordinates and the respective 3D feature points, i.e, how can I determine to which feature point each of the projections belongs?

Comment: If you know the 3D coordinates, the 2D coordinates, and the projection transform, then this would appear to be trivial (assuming that none of the coordinates project to the same 2D point).  Just re-apply the transform to the 3D coordinates, and do some kind of closest-match thing to account for numerical error.  What am I missing?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't know the projection transform (I don't compute the projection, I just take a 2D photo of the object).

Comment: Ah, now that's important!  You should probably make that explicitly clear in your question!

Comment: But obviously, there are potentially multiple solutions to this problem without any further constraints.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks for your input. Do you think of any concrete sort of constraints that might help here?

Comment: Isn't this problem precisely the definition of the Perspective-N-Point problem, and more specifically the variant solved by OpenCV's `solvePnP()` and `solvePnPRansac()` functions? Or are you trying to match the points using some descriptor, like SIFT? Here's a link to the PnP problem: http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/11/pose-estimation-problem/

Comment: This differs from `solvePnP` because we don't know the correspondences of 3D points to 2D points.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is not a solution to your problem. Imagine you take a picture of regular tetrahedra. Now rotate it by 120° you get the same picture but the points are different. So you need more info.

Comment: Yes, there are configurations of 3D points for which there is no unique solution. But in general case, when there are more than ten 3D points with known coordinates but irregularly positioned, there should be a way to discover which projection corresponds to which ID.