# Computing a Projection Matrix with Image/Object Points

Tags: c++, computer-vision

I've been trying to understand how to compute a projection matrix using image points and object points (3D and 2D points), but I can't seem to find a clear understanding of how you'd do this. I have a function as follows:

```
void calculateprojectionmatrix(Mat image_points, Mat object_points, Mat projection_matrix)
```

I've tried researching solutions for this (preferably in a C++ implementation), but can't find any clear explanation, and no background resources I can find seem to shed enough light on the topic. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have this function already implemented, call it.  If you need to *implement* this function, you'll need to show *some* effort towards doing so.

Comment: I'm sorry if it comes off as "lazy" or a lack of effort, but it's hard for me to start when I don't understand the procedure to manipulate these points to begin with. If it was a matter of debugging an implementation, I would have included my implementation with the question. The truth is, I've spent hours researching and I simply can't find enough information to create an implementation. I'm not asking for it to be done for me, but simply for help in understanding.

Comment: So you don't know *anything* about computing a projection matrix, or even what it *is*, and can't do anything other than name what this function is supposed to do, and don't even specify what the type it uses (`Mat`) is.  That's not a lot to work with.

Comment: Okay, I understand that a projection matrix is a 4x3 matrix (or Mat object) that is used to transform homogeneous coordinates in a world coordinate frame to an image coordinate frame. I understand that it can be calculated as K[R|T] ((Camera Calibration matrix) * [Rotation matrix | Translation matrix]), and that's how I've traditionally learned to form it. Also, the Mat type is (CV_32F - 32 bit float). The problem is that I don't understand how to create it based on image/object points. Would I calculate the K,R,T matrices and then use the formula I know?

Comment: I think I have a good lead on my question, after re-reading some notes. I'll post details as an answer once I confirm that I have a working solution for others to reference. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're using openCV you may want to scan some of the OpenCV docs.

Say, like initCameraMatrix2D ?

You might want to read [Find 2D-3D correspondence of 4 non-coplanar points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776105/find-2d-3d-correspondence-of-4-non-coplanar-points?rq=1)